# reactjs ---> useReducer topic

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

in the reactjs I am not understand the below code please help me in this

```
...todo, complete: !todo.complete
```

according to me first ...todo is the spread array, and after comma the condition has been implemented on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's vanilla JavaScript, nothing related to react here

This is not a condition

```
!false -> true
!true -> false
```

Doing this:

```
const todo = {
  name: 'Something to do',
  complete: false
}

const newTodo = {
  ...todo,
  complete: !todo.complete
}
```

Results in:

```
{
  name: 'Something to do',
  complete: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is spread operator.

> The JavaScript spread operator (...) allows us to quickly copy all or
> part of an existing array or object into another array or object.

[you can read more in this link](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Spread Operator, just plain JS, nothing related to React.

When you use the spread operator:

```js
const todo = {
  completed: false,
  title: "Test"
};

const sameTodo = { ...todo };
```

The `sameTodo` variable will be the same as the `todo` variable.

```js
// sameTodo
{
  completed: false,
  title: "Test"
}
```

In the example you gave in the question, it will first create a new object and then add the values of the todo object to it

Eg:

```js
const todo = {
  completed: false,
  title: "Something"
}

/*
Value of `changedTodo`:

{
  completed: false,
  title: "Something"
}

*/
const changedTodo = {
  ...todo
}
```

And then it says

```js
complete: !todo.complete
```

The `!` Mark is a logical 'Not' operator, it will change a value to its opposite.

Eg:

```js
// True will become false & false will become true
!true --> false
!false --> true
```

So when we get back to `changedTodo`, we can add the operator to the `completed` property:

```js
const changedTodo = {
  ...todo,
  completed: !todo.completed
}
```

And when you assign a property that already exists in an object that you are spreading, it will overwrite it.

So, here the `todo` object already has a `completed` property, so when we use
`completed: !todo.completed`, it will overwrite what was on the todo object and change it to it's opposite.

Since here the todo object has the `completed` property as `false`, it will turn to `true`

So in the end, we get this:

```
const changedTodo = {
  title: "Something",
  completed: true
}
```

By the way, this has nothing to do with React or useReducer. This is plain vanilla Javascript.

Hope this helps.